# Print differences between list of lists using Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have two list of lists like below. I know I can use set(list1)-set(list2) or vice-versa to print the list that's different from the other corresponding one. However, I do not want the complete list to be printed out, I just want that part of the list that's been modified.

For example, list1:

```
[['Code', 'sID', 'dID', 'cID', 'ssID'], ['ABCD-00', 'ABCD-00-UNK', '358', '1234', '9999'], ['ABCD-01', 'ABCD-00-UNK', 160, '993', '587']]
```

list2:

```
[['Code', 'sID', 'dID', 'cID', 'ssID', 'AddedColumn'], ['ABCD-00', 'ABCD-00-UNK', '358', '1234', '9999', 'AddedValue1'], ['ABCD-01', 'ABCD-00-UNK', 160, '993', 'ChangedValue', 'AddedValue2']]
```

If I do set difference, it prints out the entire list. I want the output to show only the columns that are different/added/taken away when 'Code', 'sID' are the same.

EDIT:

The first list of each list of lists is the header. So I want to compare the lists when values from 'Code', 'sID' columns are matching.

Desired output:

```
Added - ['AddedColumn', 'AddedValue1', 'AddedValue2']
Deleted - []
Changed - ['Code', 'ABCD-01', 'ssID', 'ChangeValue']
```

something like this or anything simpler is fine also.

Comment: What does _'Code','sID' are the same_ means? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) to work out how your lists have changed:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

matcher = SequenceMatcher()
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    matcher.set_seqs(a, b)
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in matcher.get_opcodes():
        if tag == 'equal': continue
        print('{:>7s} {} {}'.format(tag, a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]))
```

This simple setup only lists what things have been added, deleted, or replaced:

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> list1 = [['Code', 'sID', 'dID', 'cID', 'sID'], ['ABCD-00', 'ABCD-00-UNK', '358', '1234', '9999'], ['ABCD-01', 'ABCD-00-UNK', 160, '993', '587']]
>>> list2 = [['Code', 'sID', 'dID', 'cID', 'sID', 'AddedColumn'], ['ABCD-00', 'ABCD-00-UNK', '358', '1234', '9999', 'AddedValue1'], ['ABCD-01', 'ABCD-00-UNK', 160, '993', 'ChangedValue', 'AddedValue2']]
>>> matcher = SequenceMatcher()
>>> for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
...     matcher.set_seqs(a, b)
...     for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in matcher.get_opcodes():
...         if tag == 'equal': continue
...         print('{:>7s} {} {}'.format(tag, a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]))
... 
 insert [] ['AddedColumn']
 insert [] ['AddedValue1']
replace ['587'] ['ChangedValue', 'AddedValue2']
```

but the matcher also gives you what hasn't changed; I ignored the `equal` tags to simplify the demo. It shows how two elements have been added, and one element was replaced by two other elements.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. But if you don't mind, could you please briefly explain what `'{:>7s} {} {}'` this part means.

Comment: @amy that's a format string that the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) uses to fill in values. `>7s` creates a column 7 characters wide with the value right-aligned in the final string. See [*Format String Syntax*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 0):

`set(a) - set(b)` returns the elements that are in list a, but not list b. To view elements added to a list, use `set(newList) - set(oldList)`, to view elements removed from a list use `set(oldList) - set(newList)`.

You cannot apply if you apply `set` on a list of list in python 3 (I do not know about python 2) you get the following error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. So you will have to apply this to each of the corresponding sublists.

Comment: I converted them into sets, which I didn't mention here.